# How do I do casting in Scala?

Tags: scala, casting

For example suppose I have

```
val myDouble = 25.7
val myInt = 5
```

How would I do something like

```
val divide = (Int) (myDouble / myInt)
```

Comment: I'm not that sure, but IMHO, we talk about casting, if we transform an object, which is guaranteed to be of class BASE to class DERIVED (and we do so, if we know it is of type DERIVED, but can't prove it to the compiler). While for the arithmetic types, they aren't derived from each other, so I think we don't call it 'casting' then - but I'm not sure (but I'm sure, that Int isn't derived from Double). So instanceOf[Int] is the way of casting, but toInt is a method defined in Double, and more type safe - I would prefer it.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can do `(myDouble/myInt).toInt`. You can also do `toDouble`, `toLong`, and `toFloat`.

Comment: just to add to this answer, if it doesn't have a to_ method you can use .asInstanceOf[T]

Comment: Agreed, the asInstanceOf is very useful. Thanks for the addition.

Comment: According to the Scala api for toInt: "This may involve rounding or truncation." Which one of the two then, rounding *or* truncation?

Answer (score 19):

My prefered way is to add a rounding method, to reduce any potential suprise in the conversion behavior:

```
val divide = (myDouble/myInt).ceil.toInt
```

or

```
val divide = (myDouble/myInt).floor.toInt
```

Answer (score 4):

or you could do...

```
 scala> val myDouble = 25.7
 myDouble: Double = 25.7

 scala> val myInt = 5
 myInt: Int = 5

 scala> val divide = (myDouble / myInt).asInstanceOf[Int]
 divide: Int = 5
```