# How does Scala convert Int to Double?

Tags: scala, coercion

```
val d: Double = 42
```

When I try to find implicit conversion via intellij, nothing interesting comes up. Also, `Int` isn't a subtype of `Double`. So how does Scala do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do casting in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714967/how-do-i-do-casting-in-scala)

Comment: @Stoopkid In a sense, my question is the opposite of that thread: I'm almost asking why I *don't* need a `.toDouble`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Long story short: it's not an ordinary implicit conversion on some companion object, the numerical types get a special treatment.

---

If we run `scala -print` on this script:

```
val d: Double = 42
```

we obtain:

```
package <empty> {
  object Main extends Object {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      new <$anon: Object>();
      ()
    };
    def <init>(): Main.type = {
      Main.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  };
  final class anon$1 extends Object {
    private[this] val d: Double = _;
    <stable> <accessor> private def d(): Double = anon$1.this.d;
    def <init>(): <$anon: Object> = {
      anon$1.super.<init>();
      anon$1.this.d = 42.0;
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

In the desugared code, we see a double literal `42.0`, but no invocations of any conversion 
functions (e.g. from `Predef`). Thus, the conversion from `Int` to `Double` must take place not 
at runtime, but at earlier stages of compilation.

The [section 3.5.3 of the specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#weak-conformance)
tells us that `Int` *weakly conforms* to `Double` because of the transitivity of the weak conformance relation `<:w`:

```
Int <:w Long <:w Float <:w Double
```

Furthermore, [Section 6.26.1 (Value Conversions)](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#value-conversions)
tells us that rules for *numeric widening* are applicable if an expression `e` of type `T` appears in position where an expression of
type `pt` is expected and `T` weakly conforms to `pt`. In this case, we can apply the rule with

- expression `e = 42`
- type of expression `T = Int`
- expected type `pt = Double`

Thus, `42` is converted to `42.0` using `toDouble`. Since it's a constant that can be processed at compile time, 
we don't see the `toDouble` in the desugared code. However, if we desugar a similar program with a non-constant
value

```
val d: Double = (new scala.util.Random).nextInt(42)
```

we obtain:

```
package <empty> {
  object Main extends Object {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      new <$anon: Object>();
      ()
    };
    def <init>(): Main.type = {
      Main.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  };
  final class anon$1 extends Object {
    private[this] val d: Double = _;
    <stable> <accessor> private def d(): Double = anon$1.this.d;
    def <init>(): <$anon: Object> = {
      anon$1.super.<init>();
      anon$1.this.d = new scala.util.Random().nextInt(42).toDouble();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

and the `toDouble` is there, as specified.

Comment: Very informative, especially re: the weak conformance details.  My assumption of the Int-to-Double implicit conversion being at play under the hood is incorrect then.

Comment: @LeoC It's a plausible assumption, though. I can't spontaneously invent an example where one would actually notice the difference without looking at the desugared code.